# How can I delete files with CakePHP and Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, ajax-upload

I'm in a page called 'add.cpt' that has a list of images. The user has the option to remove the images but I can't make it work. In the event of click I try to call an ajax trying to pass the name of the image and id of the item (.../item/imageName) but it does delete the image and alerts what seems to be the content of delete_photo_file.ctp. It looks like the ajax is using the URL but it is not sending the data to delete the file wanted.

ItemsController:

```
App::uses('File', 'Utility');
class ItemsController extends AppController{

[...]

public function deletePhotoFile(){
  //$this->autoRender = false; //did not tested but maybe I need to use this
  $imgName = //don't know how to get it from ajax call
  $itemId = //don't know how to get it from ajax call
  $file = new File($dir.'/'.$itemId.'/'.$imgName);
  $file->delete();
} 

}
```

Ajax Call (from my ctp file):

```
$('#delete').click(function (){
[...]

var itemId=$('#itemId').val(); //comes from hidden input
var imgName = $('#imgName').val(); //comes from hidden input

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url:'http://localhost/html/Project/v5/CakeStrap/items/deletePhotoFile/',
  data:{"itemId":itemId, imgName: imgName},
  success: function(data){
    alert(data); //alerts some HTML... seems to be delete_photo_file.ctp content
  }
});

});
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: "does not work"? how so? leans against its shovel and gossips all day? crashes? deletes the wrong file? writes naughty words in other files?

Comment: It looks like the ajax is using the URL but it is not sending the data to delete the file wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ItemsController, make sure you actually load the File utility class, by adding:

```
App::uses('File', 'Utility');
```

Just below the opening `<?php` tag before your class definition. In your action you can just use `$this->request->data` to get the data keys. Also, return the action of the `delete()` function, so you can trigger your AJAX success/error call accordingly.

```
public function deletePhotoFile() {
    $imgName = $this->request->data['imgName'];
    $itemId = $this->request->data['itemId'];
    /**
     * Where is the $dir below actually set? Make sure to pass it properly!
     * Furthermore, it's always cleaner to use DS constant
     * (short for DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR), so the code will work on any OS
     */
    $file = new File($dir . DS . $itemId . DS . $imgName);
    return $file->delete();
}
```

Finally, mind your quotes in the AJAX call:

```
data:{"itemId":itemId, imgName: imgName},
```

Should become:

```
data:{"itemId":itemId, "imgName": imgName},
```

As otherwise, you just call the `imgName` JS var twice.

Comment: I forgot to put the `App::uses('File', 'Utility');` in the question but I was using it (edited it now). I'll try your answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried to use debug($imgName) and debug($itemId) and they are printing the right data but still not working. Maybe I made some mistake with the path of the file.

Comment: Solved! Needed to use `WWW_ROOT`.
`$dir = WWW_ROOT.'files' . DS . 'Item' . DS . $itemId . DS . $photoName;`

Answer (score 1):

In the php `$imgName = $this->request->data('imgName'); $itemId = $this->request->data('imgId');` In the js you might want to put quotes around the variable name since it's the same as the name of the value being passed `data: {'itemId': itemId, 'imgName': imgName},`

Comment: Accessing `$_POST` directly is not the CakePHP way.

Comment: Just pointing out the issue, I use CI so the references would likely differ. Assume the poster knows enough to use the correct object to access the vars. Next time a correction instead of just a simple down-vote might be more helpful. something like... `$imgName = $this->request->data('imgName');` editing original response

Comment: sorry for the assumption. somebody did :(

Answer (score 0):

To get the data out simply `debug($this->request->data)` in your `deletePhotoFile()` method and check the response in your browsers console, it should be a nicely formatted array with the data you POST`d over in your ajax request, you should be able to work out the rest from there.

You'll also want to look into using the [RequestHandler component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html) so you can assure the request is an ajax request.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. And how about my code to delete the file? Is it correct? (`$file = new File($dir.'/'.$itemId.'/'.$imgName);
  $file->delete();`).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as I've never worked with the File class myself, best bet is to just try it and see.